# Count the maximum number of continuous not null columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have  a table in the following structureL

```
{col_a1,  ..      ,Col_a15, Continuous_count}
```

These columns might have either a NULL or a particular value (in col_a1 to col_a15).

I need to find out the most continuous set of data and keep the count in the column `continuous_count`. For example:

```
Columns: col_a1   col_a2  col_a3  col_a4  col_a5  col_a6  col_a7  Continuous_count
ROW_1:    NULL     NULL     2       2       3      NULL    2           3
ROW_2:    NULL     1        2       2       3      NULL    2           4
ROW_3:    NULL     NULL     NULL    2       3      NULL    2           2
ROW_4:    2        1        2       2       3      NULL    2           5
```

I am not able to write the query, i wrote one but looks too big with a lot of ifs and else's. is there a simple method to do this.

Comment: The necessity to do this would probably indicate that these are meant to be rows rather than columns... A simple `count(*)` would then suffice.

Comment: for example in your table, you need to display only `ROW_4`

Comment: Based on the count i am deriving the column continuous_count which is the last column. i cannot simply take a count(*) because it will return all the not null columns. I dont want that.

Comment: I understand @vik123. I'm saying that you shouldn't be doing this on continuous columns but continuous rows, i.e. the necessity of doing this would indicate that your data model might need changing.

Comment: Yes i got you point @ben. actually we have pivoted the data long back and using it for report purposes. Now they have asked for some CR's on this. Changing the model would impact at several places. So i asked it in this way. But anyways if there is no other solution available. changing the model will be the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see is check for all combinations of adjacent columns.

I am using `power(1,col_ax)` below to get 1 for any value and null for null. When adding, combinations having at least one null result in null (and thus in 0 for the use of NVL, because otherwise GREATEST would result in null).

```
select mytable.*,
  greatest
  (
    nvl(power(1,col_a1), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a1) + power(1,col_a2), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a1) + power(1,col_a2) + power(1,col_a3), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a1) + power(1,col_a2) + power(1,col_a3) + power(1,col_a4), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a1) + power(1,col_a2) + power(1,col_a3) + power(1,col_a4) + power(1,col_a5), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a1) + power(1,col_a2) + power(1,col_a3) + power(1,col_a4) + power(1,col_a5) + power(1,col_a6), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a1) + power(1,col_a2) + power(1,col_a3) + power(1,col_a4) + power(1,col_a5) + power(1,col_a6) + power(1,col_a7), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a2), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a2) + power(1,col_a3), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a2) + power(1,col_a3) + power(1,col_a4), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a2) + power(1,col_a3) + power(1,col_a4) + power(1,col_a5), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a2) + power(1,col_a3) + power(1,col_a4) + power(1,col_a5) + power(1,col_a6), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a2) + power(1,col_a3) + power(1,col_a4) + power(1,col_a5) + power(1,col_a6) + power(1,col_a7), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a3), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a3) + power(1,col_a4), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a3) + power(1,col_a4) + power(1,col_a5), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a3) + power(1,col_a4) + power(1,col_a5) + power(1,col_a6), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a3) + power(1,col_a4) + power(1,col_a5) + power(1,col_a6) + power(1,col_a7), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a4), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a4) + power(1,col_a5), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a4) + power(1,col_a5) + power(1,col_a6), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a4) + power(1,col_a5) + power(1,col_a6) + power(1,col_a7), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a5), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a5) + power(1,col_a6), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a5) + power(1,col_a6) + power(1,col_a7), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a6), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a6) + power(1,col_a7), 0),
    nvl(power(1,col_a7), 0),
    0
  ) as continous_count
from mytable;
```

Comment: Will this not hit performance if i am running this query on half a million records.

Comment: Well, the task is a little complicated, so it takes some work to find the desired values. The table is read just once, however, so all in all this shouldn't be too slow. To avoid using the POWER function again and again, you can use a derived table instead: `from (select power(1,col_a1) as has1, power(1,col_a2) as has2, ... from mytable)`.

Comment: Your other option would be to write a PL/SQL function. But calling PL/SQL from SQL isn't free of cost either.